# React Native Fetch/ Axios file upload error

Tags: react-native, file-upload, axios, fetch, multipartform-data

I am facing an issue while trying to upload an image to the server from React-Native android emulator, please point me to an answer or write an answer if you faced this issue and resolved it.

```
const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', {
    uri: file.src.uri,
    name: file.src.name,
    type: file.src.type,
  });
  data.append('documentType', file.id);
   // axios({
  //   method: 'post',
  //   url: API_URL + '/users/' + user.id + '/uploadDocument',
  //   body: data,
  //   headers: {
  //     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',
  //   },
  // })
  fetch(API_URL + '/users/' + user.id + '/uploadDocument', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(async (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === 200) {
        Toast.show({
          text: 'Profile Document Uploaded Successfully',
          position: 'top',
        });
      } else {
        Toast.show({
          text: 'There was an error uploading',
          position: 'top',
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Profile img upload err', err.message);
      Toast.show({
        text: 'Unable to upload profile document',
        position: 'top',
      });
    });
```

Here is the response for Fetch-

{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "85366f42-0bb9-48e0-81f6-fb516a41efb3", "offset": 0, "size": 244}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "85366f42-0bb9-48e0-81f6-fb516a41efb3", "offset": 0, "size": 244}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"access-control-allow-headers": "x-requested-with, authorization,Content-Type", "access-control-allow-methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "access-control-max-age": "3600", "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8", "date": "Wed, 17 Feb 2021 12:34:59 GMT", "expires": "0", "pragma": "no-cache", "server": "nginx/1.12.1", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-frame-options": "DENY", "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"}}, "ok": false, "status": 400, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "https://xxxxxx.yyyyyy.in/users/422/uploadDocument"}

Axios fails with 400 or 500 error code

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be hard to tell what the error is without some more info from the server. A `400 Bad Request` error indicates there is a problem with the payload you are sending. Probably the file mime type or the content itself.

The `500 Internal Error` response probably indicates something you are sending is causing an exception server-side (mainly because the server was poorly coded to handle incorrect payloads).

Comment: Thank you, even the error message message from backend was not clear, so, I tried Fetch instead.